# ng-repeat next and previous navigation

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for a way to implement ng-repeat next-prevous navigation. Navigation is inside repeating area, so the navigation arrows are shown if next or previous items exists.

But I need a way to add an active class to repeater on ng-click, so if I navigate to next item, it receives active class (and same with previous), so i can make that item visible and all other hidden.

```
<li ng-class="{active: ?}" ng-repeat="page in pages">
  <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="page.content"></p>
  <a ng-show="pages[$index - 1]" ng-click="?" class="previous" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a ng-show="pages[$index + 1]" ng-click="?" class="next" href="#">Next</a>                                          
</li>
```

Also if there is another way around this, please advise.

Comment: Can you draw an example of what you want to do? It's not clear to me. And why are you showing the page content inside a list item? Shouldn't you take the pagination control and the rendering of the actual page content apart?

Comment: The pagination control is inside so I easily calculate / render nav if next/previous item exist, but if you have better way :) . I just need to hide all items except one that is currently viewed (all are rendered)

Comment: AngularUI Bootstrap has the navigation controller directive built in. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-class="{active: activePage.page == $index, 
    inactive: activePage.page != $index}" ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="page.content"></p>
        <a ng-show="pages[$index - 1]" ng-click="activePage.page = $index-1" 
        class="previous" href="#">Previous</a>
        <a ng-show="pages[$index + 1]" ng-click="activePage.page = $index+1" 
        class="next" href="#">Next</a>                                          
    </li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active{
    display:block;
}

.inactive{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    /* Dont use a primitive but an object as ng-repeat creates 
       a scope of its own */
    $scope.activePage = {
        page:0
    };
    $scope.pages = [{content:"a"},{content:"b"},{content:"c"}];
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is what I have looking for. Only it seems that it does not support multiple ng-includes, so i need somehow to tell individual instances that they have unique navigation...

Comment: I had to remove the href="#" from the previous and next link to make it work (using Angular 1.3.8)